# How Can I use AR.js in Ionic Framework?

Tags: ionic-framework, augmented-reality, ar.js

I am able to use the code on chrome browser but the code does not seem to work on Ionic. [https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js](http://AR.js)

Or is their any other open source AR technology that I can use for Ionic. EzarTech isn't powerful enough for my application.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this yet?